# how does one get the profile from a user in DJango

Tags: python, django, pycharm, profile

I have code that is like the following for people logging in:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

if user:
    # Check it the account is active
    if user.is_active:

        # Log the user in.
        login(request, user)
```

I have extended the User to create a UserProfile. It contains other information. Ex: address, city, state, etc.

How would one extract the User profile from this situation? For Java under Eclipse, if I typed in "user", I would see all of the *valid* methods that would apply to the object "user".

It does not appear that PyCharm has such a feature.

With that being said, how can one find the profile information associated with a user?

TIA

Below is the Profile Model Code:

```
class UserProfileInfo (models.Model):
    class Meta:

        db_table = 'mstrauthdjprofile'
        db_tablespace = 'PSAPUSR1001'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    restrole = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    lastpgprocno = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=-1)
    currentpgprocno = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=-1)
    nextpgprocno = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)

    reclocktype = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    reclockid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Add your Profile model code

Comment: @NeErAj KuMaR - have added it to the message. Any ideas?

Comment: try `user.userprofileinfo` to get profile object and first `user` should be django default user instance

Answer (score 2):

`OneToOneField`s are always accessible from their counterparts.

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
user.userprofileinfo

user = User.objects.first()
user.userprofileinfo

user_profile_info = UserProfileInfo.objects.first()
user_profile_info.user
```

You can use a debugger like pdb by inserting a breakpoint in your code (I believe PyCharm should have an automated way to handle this):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Which will allow you to interact with the current scope. You can view what attributes a object has with `__dict__`

```
user.__dict__
{'username': 'user', 'id': 1, ...}
```

Also consider a more powerful/interactive debugger like IPython or bpython, which have auto-complete built in.